# Find driver element with Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, python-webbrowser, findelement

I am trying to download a file from MS Edge. The webpage is protected by a username and a password. I am able to open up MS Edge, and navigate to the appropriate page, however, I can't navigate the UserName and PassWord box.

An error appears as follows:

TypeError: Object of type builtin_function_or_method is not JSON serializable

I have tried a larger program, but broke it down to the following simple steps, since I am in debugging-mode:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Edge() #Edge opens

time.sleep(3)

driver.get("my_URL") #Webpage opens

time.sleep(3)

id_box = driver.find_element(id,"correct_id") #Error Occurs
```

Comment: Can we see the `box` , `box source` or probably `url` if possible to understand your issue.

Comment: URL:   https://interactive.advantage.am/Portal/Secure/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fAlphaAccess%2fStatements

Comment: Unable to access the `URL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to search like that:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


id_box = driver.find_element(By.ID,"correct_id")
```

Because only `id` isn't a valid object.